# Keras report highly inconsistent loss between 2 optimization runs

Tags: optimization, keras

I am trying to classify some images if they contain object : Yes or No.

I firstly run 50 epochs with rmsprop optimizer and continue with second run of SGD optimizer with more 50 epochs.

My first run ends with loss ~ 0.4 and model is saved . Second run starts with the saved model.

The problem that at start of second run Keras shows that loss is ~ 0.8 at 1 epoch.

Why could it happen for same loss function ?

Answer (score 1):

Your new SGD optimizer is not optimized for that model. The moments and the adaptive learning rate were forgotten.

Thus, there is indeed a high chance that this new compilation start badly.

You can try to restart with lower learning rates, and also try to add moment to the SGD.

Comment: Thanks Daniel . It helped